# Aptana 3 Studio's debug console delays output until script termination

Tags: aptana

I've installed Aptana Studio 3.0.1 as an eclipse plugin and ruby 1.9.2p180. When I run a ruby script from Aptana and track its execution on the **debug console**, it delays the output until script finalization.

Here is a simple code example:

```
puts "Hello world!"
print "Enter a phrase: "
puts gets
```

When I run this program on Aptana, I get this output

```
Test
Hello world!
Enter a phrase: Test
```

But running it on ruby interpreter gives me a different result:

```
ruby test.rb

Hello world!
Enter a phrase: Test
Test
```

The latter is the correct output.

What's happening?
Maybe I found a bug in Aptana or is it due to a misconfiguration?

Answer (score 1):

Well there's two explanations:

1. There was a bug that could cause this in 3.0.0. (See http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-806 and http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2088 ). Those should have been fixed in 3.0.1, so that may not be the cause.
2. Ruby sometimes buffers up output to STDERR/STDOUT (specifically on Windows we tend to see this). You can force them to flush by adding the following in your code:

   ```
   STDERR.sync = true
   STDOUT.sync = true
   ```

   There was a fix in 3.0.2 where we silently do this for you: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2355